# html5gallery not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

I'm trying to display Photo Gallery Carousel using **html5gallery** and **jwplayer**. It is working fine in chrome and ie but not working firefox. It throws the above error continuously in time interval as like,

> browserLink (line 64)
>   88
>
> [10:07:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
>   SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
>
> browserLink (line 64)
>   94
>
> [10:07:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
>   SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
>
> browserLink (line 64)
>   100
>
> [10:07:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
>   SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Thanks in advance for your help..!

Comment: Try removing the jwplayer and html5Gallery one by one to track down what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error thrown by *BrowserLink* feature of **Visual Studio 2013**. By default, the feature is enabled. You can disable it to get rid of such errors.
Refer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx